# Java 11 add .pem to cacerts

Tags: java

I try to equip some corporate JDKs with certificates. For Java 8 it was done like this:

```
keytool -importcert -file cert.pem -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias alias
```

When I do this with Java 11 it is still working, but I get a warning:

> Warnung: Verwenden Sie die Option -cacerts für den Zugriff auf den
> cacerts Keystore
>
> **Translation:** Warning: Use the option -cacerts für access to cacerts keystore

But I don't know what to do with -cacerts option.

Comment: Did you try to simply replace `-keystore cacerts` with `-cacerts`? I guess it's just a shortcut.

Comment: Ok I feel dumb now. With this the warning vanished. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace `-keystore cacerts` with `-cacerts` to avoid this warning. [More info](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html).